# Get User-Input From WPF DataGrid Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datagrid, textbox

I'm new to WPF, but I'm somewhat familiar with DataGrids in older versions of .net.  I have a DataGrid in WPF that is bound to a DataTable, filled through a SQLDataAdapter from an SQL query.  I'm using DataGridTextColumn binding for the fields from my query (they are output as ReadOnly on the grid).   I also have another DataGridTemplateColumn with a TextBox.  This textbox is not bound to any data and it appears on each row adjacent to the data.  The user can enter in the TextBox adjacent to the row.  Finally, I have another DataGridTemplateColumn for a button that calls a Sub to retrieve user-selected (and user-entered data).   Upon click I have a code-behind Sub to retrieve the selected row and specified column value (I've accomplished this) AND I want to retrieve the input that the user has entered into the texbox.  It is the latter than I cannot figure out how to do.  I've researched for hours.  I've seen similiar solutions, but not exactly what I'm trying to do.   I cannot figure out how to get the user's input from the textbox for the selected row.  Here is my XAML, code-behind Sub, and screen shot.

```
            <!--bound columns-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InvProjectID}" Header="InvProjectID" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NSN}" Header="NSN" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Nomenclature}" Header="Nomenclature" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True"/>

            <!--select button-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="SelectInvProjectID">Select</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!--textbox-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="mytextbox">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtUserEnteredText" Width="50"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

```
Private Sub SelectInvProjectID(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    'set selected column and row selected to variable (column name is InvProjectID)
    Dim strSelectedInvProjectID As String = ""
    strSelectedInvProjectID = dgTestGrid.SelectedItem("InvProjectID")

    'set entered text to variable HOW????
    Dim strUserEnteredText As String = ""
    'strUserEnteredText = ??????????

    MessageBox.Show("Selected InvProjectID = " & strSelectedInvProjectID & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Text Entered = " & strUserEnteredText)

End Sub
```

[WPF Datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic4jm.png)

Comment: Use MVVM and this would be a piece of cake!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm new to WPF and MVVM seems very abstract to me.  I'm unclear if its a toolkit or just a different way of utilizing certain classes available tp WPF.  I've seen several MVVM articles but nothing is clear enough to me to understand the wiring.  And it seems I read about some unexpected behavior (bugs?) in MVVM, but I could be misinterpreting that.  IMO I don't think my requirement is that unique.  I'd think there should be a way to use the base DataGrid WPF to accomplish what I'm looking for.  But, any detail you or anyone else could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution.  Needed to wire-up ContentPresenter to the column with textbox (column 4) and the user-selected row and set that to a ContentTemplate.  Then use the .FindName method.

```
    Dim myCp As ContentPresenter = dgTestGrid.Columns(4).GetCellContent(dgTestGrid.SelectedItem)
    Dim myTemplate = myCp.ContentTemplate
    Dim mytxtbox As TextBox = myTemplate.FindName("txtUserEnteredText", myCp)
    strUserEnteredText = mytxtbox.Text
```

Reference article below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f7a712a-5eec-4c0b-87cb-e131a3cb546b/how-do-you-get-the-control-inside-a-wpf-datagridcell?forum=wpf